# Powershell function returns an invalid object

Tags: powershell

Here are 2 equivalent code samples, the only difference is that first sample uses function while other does not.

This code fails, because function returns invalid object:

```
function Initialize-Table
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string] $TableName = "InstallationTable"
    )

    # Create Table object
    $InstallTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "$TableName"

    # Define Columns
    $UserColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn User, ([string])
    $InstallColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn InstallRoot, ([string])

    # Add the Columns
    $InstallTable.Columns.Add($UserColumn)
    $InstallTable.Columns.Add($InstallColumn)

    return $InstallTable
}

Write-Host "Initialize-Table"
Write-Host "***************************"
$InstallTable = Initialize-Table

if (!$InstallTable)
{
    Write-Warning "Table not initialized"
    exit
}
```

However following is exactly the same, except that function code is put directly into script, and the table is valid!

```
Write-Host "Initialize-Table"
Write-Host "***************************"
$TableName = "InstallationTable"
# Create Table object
$InstallTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "$TableName"

# Define Columns
$UserColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn User, ([string])
$InstallColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn InstallRoot, ([string])

# Add the Columns
$InstallTable.Columns.Add($UserColumn)
$InstallTable.Columns.Add($InstallColumn)

if (!$InstallTable)
{
    Write-Warning "Table not initialized"
    exit
}
```

Why my function does not work (first sample)? it's the same damn code.

Comment: I notice a difference, you never define $TableName in the 2nd code.

Comment: @BillyHudson ok, I forgot while posting a question, I'll update my sample, but that isn't an issue.

Comment: In what way is the returned object invalid?

Comment: It's invalid because `if(!$InstallTable)` check fails, and I'm unable to use the variable to write and read data into the table.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by making the table global variable, it's unfortunate that in powershell `return` means write to stdout. (so powershell tries to write NET object to console) in every programming language `return` does exactly what it's name implies, but here `return` mean `no return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official PowerShell documentation the results of each statement are returned as output, even without a statement that contains the Return keyword. Languages like C or C# return only the value or values that are specified by the return keyword.

> but when you return a collection from your script block or function,
>   PowerShell automatically unrolls the members and passes them one at a
>   time through the pipeline. This is due to PowerShell's one-at-a-time
>   processing

.

To force a script block or function to return collection as a single object to the pipeline use either **Unary array expression** or **Write-Output with NoEnumerate parameter**

e.g. `return  Write-Output -NoEnumerate $InstallTable;` or return ( , $InstallTable);

so below code snippet works well

```
function Initialize-Table
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string] $TableName = "InstallationTable"
    )

    # Create Table object
    $InstallTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "$TableName"

    # Define Columns
    $UserColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn User, ([string])
    $InstallColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn InstallRoot, ([string])

    # Add the Columns
    $InstallTable.Columns.Add($UserColumn)
    $InstallTable.Columns.Add($InstallColumn)


    return  Write-Output -NoEnumerate $InstallTable;
}

Write-Host "Initialize-Table"
Write-Host "***************************"
$InstallTable = Initialize-Table

if (!$InstallTable)
{
    Write-Warning "Table not initialized"
    exit
}
```

Comment: Thank you and Dmitry, +1 for both, I'm already rewriting my code.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
return ,$InstallTable
```

Comma operator creates array with 1 member. It will unroll when returning, leaving $InstallTable object intact.